# Trying to Sort Array List Without All Elements

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list

The array I created has 20 elements, but the code doesn't require that a user enters all 20 items at the same time. They can enter any number of items under 20, and then click a button to display the values they have entered so far.

I can figure out how to sort the array, and how to display all 20 elements, but I can't figure out how to adjust my code to show ONLY the values they've entered. Using the code below, if a user enters only 5 of 20 elements, they get a whole bunch of 0's as well as their values.

```
 private void btnDisplayScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string scoresString = "";
        foreach (int s in scores)
            scoresString += s + "\n";
        MessageBox.Show(scoresString, "Sorted Scores");

        txtScore.Focus();
    }
```

Apologies if this is a dumb question, I'm just starting out at programming.

Comment: You need to keep track somehow how many numbers the user entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the overload of [`Sort(T[] array, int from, int length)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kszeddc.aspx) that takes two more parameters indicating the initial index and the length of the sub-array to be sorted. For example, if the user entered `K` elements, you can sort the range from zero to `K` like this:

```
int[] myArray = new int[20];
int K = ... // This variable is set to the number of items the user enters
Array.Sort(myArray, 0, K);
```

A better solution is to avoid sizing your array before you know how many elements it is going to have. The best solution is using a container that lets you add items dynamically, such as `List<T>`.

Comment: I'd love to avoid sizing the array, but the instructions say I have to.
I tried to do a int scoreEnterCount = scoreEnterCount + 1, and then in the btnDisplayScore_Click event, added Array.Sort (scores, 0, scoreEnteredCount);. It did sort of them, but it still showed all 20 elements instead of just what the user had entered.

Comment: @MichelleFarley Then the three-argument `Sort()` method should be the right one for you. Did you give it a try?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I tried Array.Sort(), which did sort them, but showed all 20 elements. For example, if a user entered (89, 92, 97, 98) if I did the Array.Sort (scores, 0, scoreEnteedCount); it sorted them but displayed (89, 92, 97, 98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...etc).

Comment: @MichelleFarley So the sorting is right, then. Now it's a display problem - you need to stop printing when you reach the `scoreEnteedCount` limit.

Comment: Correct. I tried this:  int counter;
            for (counter= 0; counter < scoreEnterCount; counter++)
                scoresString += scores[scoreCount] + "\n";
            MessageBox.Show("The totals are:\n" +
                scoresString + "\n", "Sorted  Scores");*/ 
It did display only the number of items the user had entered, but not the score values themselves. So if a user entered (87, 92, 98) it would display (0,0,0.)

Comment: @MichelleFarley Why would it display `(0,0,0)` if after sorting your array has ` (89, 92, 97, 98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...etc)`?

Comment: That's the weird thing, I can't get it to sort that way. I tried using Array.Sort(scores); and it still displays the (0,0,0,0).

Comment: I think you need *both* approaches that @dasblinkenlight has shown you.  You need, not `Array.Sort(scores)`, but `(Array.Sort(scores, 0, itemCount)`.  *And* you need the modified `for` loop that iterates only over `itemCount` items from the sorted array.  With both of those changes you'll get what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use some kind of `List` data structure, e.g. `List<T>` instead of array.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches that you could use for this.  You could use a `List` instead of an array to store your scores.  A list doesn't have a fixed size, so you'd need to add some code to prevent the user from entering more than twenty items.

If you'd like to continue to use an array, you could add a second variable to your program to track the number of items that the user has entered, say, `itemCount`.  Then you could use [this overload of Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kszeddc.aspx) to sort only populated values in the array, and you could change your `foreach` loop to a `for` loop that iterates only over the values that have actually been entered.

```
for (int ct = 0; ct < itemCount; ct++)
{
    scoresString += s + "\n";
    ' etc
}
```

Comment: I added the itemCount as a global variable so my other method (the one that gets the user-entered values) could access it. It does limit the display to only the itemCount, but it doesn't display the actual values the user enters.

So if a user enters 4 scores (87, 92, 98, 97), with the code above, it does display only 4 values.... but all values are 0.

Comment: I would guess that your sort routine is sorting all the zeros before the other values.  If that's right, it means that you need to change your sort code only to sort the first `itemCount` values: `Array.Sort(scores, 0, itemCount)`

Answer (score 1):

use List, sort it, then display

```
        List<int> i = new List<int>();
        i.Add(20);
        i.Add(4);
        i.Add(2);
        i.Add(5000);
        i.Add(65);
        i.Sort();

        foreach (int ii in i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ii);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
private void btnDisplayScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Join("\n",
        scores
            .Where(s => s > 0)
            .OrderBy(s => s)), "Sorted Scores");
    txtScore.Focus();
}
```

Comment: This assumes that it is not possible to score a zero.

Comment: @RaymondChen - Yes, very true. Easy adjusted to suit actual requirements.